Library not being found
I am getting the following error when running a Java Project:
/home/morpho/lib64/libMorphoSmartSDKJavaWrapper.so.6.45.0.0: libmorphosdk.so.6: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

The problem is that libmorphosdk.so.6 is well there. Im using ldd to find the dependencies and I am finding some anomalies.
Notice the line libmorphosdk.so.6 => not found
[noor@fedora lib64]$ ldd libMorphoSmartSDKJavaWrapper.so.6.45.0.0 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe413a5000)
    libmorphosdk.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc3fb5fd000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc3fb4b7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc3fb49c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc3fb2d1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc3fb82b000)

However, in the same directory, libmorphosdk.so.6 is well there and if I do ldd libmorphosdk.so.6, I get the following. Notice again below the line libMorphoGlog.so.1 => not found
[noor@fedora lib64]$ ldd libmorphosdk.so.6
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe753f8000)
    libMorphoGlog.so.1 => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f83291f0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8329025000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8329288000)

Again, libMorphoGlog.so.1 is well there, and if I do ldd libMorphoGlog.so.1, I get the following.
[noor@fedora lib64]$ ldd libMorphoGlog.so.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc42d8c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe4a46f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe4a667000)

My question is that why is ldd saying that libraries are not there even if it is.
